# Easiest way to check if a Python string is a number without using try/except?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a Python script that does a lot of calcualtions, but sometimes the "numbers" that are passed into the formulas are not always numbers. Sometimes they are strings.

So basically, what is an easier way to write these lines of code:

```
        units = 0 if math.isnan(UNITS) else OPH_UNITS
        # the rate here could be "N/A" so the line below fails with: must be real number, not str
        rate = 0 if not rate else rate
        total = total + ((rate * units) * factor)
```

So I already have a check that makes `rate` the value of 0 if the rate is `None` but will still fail if the value is "N/A" or any other value that is not a number. What is the Pythonic way of doing this calculation without try/except so that `rate` can be any value and the calculation will work as long as `rate` is some number?

Comment: What is wrong with using `try`/`except`?

Comment: `if not isinstance(rate, [int, float])...`

Comment: I don't have it in this snippet, but I already have some nested try/excepts around this code, would rather try to make a one liner for this problem.

Comment: what do you want to happen if `rate` is `"N/A"`?

Comment: `isinstance(rate, numbers.Real)` (assuming complex numbers won't work)? With appropriate import.

Comment: If rate is "N/A" of None then I need rate to be 0

Comment: try/except with a cast to `float` would be the more concise and Pythonic way, if you want to flatten out some of your nested try/excepts you could extract some of the code into functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for `None`, instance, and number-like strings:

```py
if not rate or not str(rate).replace(".", "").isnumeric():
    rate = 0
elif isinstance(rate, str):
    if rate.isnumeric():
        rate = int(rate)
    elif rate.replace(".", "").isnumeric():
        rate = float(rate)
```

Test table

| `rate` | output | `type` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `'test'` | `0` | `<class 'int'>` |
| `'test123'` | `0` | `<class 'int'>` |
| `'123'` | `123` | `<class 'int'>` |
| `None` | `0` | `<class 'int'>` |
| `False` | `0` | `<class 'int'>` |
| `123` | `123` | `<class 'int'>` |
| `'1.1/1'` | `0` | `<class 'int'>` |
| `complex(1, 1)` | `0` | `<class 'int'>` |
| `'1.1'` | `1.1` | `<class 'float'>` |
| `1.1` | `1.1` | `<class 'float'>` |

If you're converting strictly to `int` (`floats` are `0`):

```
if not rate or not str(rate).isnumeric():
    rate = 0
elif isinstance(rate, str):
    rate = int(rate)
```

if you want to round the `float` to an `int`:

```
if not rate:
    rate = 0
elif isinstance(rate, str):
    rate = int(float(rate))
```

Overall, this does not account for **everything**. As mentioned in the comments, the `'½'` (U+00BD) unicode will be `True` for [`.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric). Which will break the program.

You could manualy go and add exceptions for all inputs, but its reccomended to just use `try` and `except`. Don't try and *one line* or simplify an expression for aesthetics when you are missing functionality.

Comment: I've upvoted, although the complexity needed in this answer to get expected results shows why it's better to use the try/except that the OP is trying to avoid for no good reason :)

Comment: @Anentropic exactly. A note to OP - One liners should not be chosen over longer expressions because "they're shorter and simple". Consider the complications of what you have left out for a visual aesthetic

Answer (score -1):

There's a method called `isnumeric()` which you can call on the string; see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) here. It returns `True` if all characters are numeric (digits or other Unicode characters with a numeric value, e.g. fractions), `False` otherwise. But my personal favourite is still `try`/`except` with a typecast to `int` or `float`.

Comment: not the downvoter, but try `'1/1.1'.isnumeric()` ;)

Comment: @mozway "1/1.1" is clearly not numeric, a bigger problem is that "1.1".isnumeric() also evaluates to false

Comment: @BendikKnapstad I added the '/' because of the "fractions" comment of Schnitte, they can try other combinations ;)

Comment: With the fractions I meant dedicated Unicode characters for some commonly used fractions, e.g. ½ (U+00BD). Those will evaluate to True under .isnumeric().